# 'jobs' tab on writer SE like in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Has it been suggested to get a 'jobs' tab much like they have in stackoverflow?  If not I'd like to suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we have the size of community for that yet. Stack Overflow is maybe *the* go-to resource on the web for questions of programming. Every mid-level programmer on this planet knows and uses that community. Therefore it makes sense to attach a job exchange to that community. Writers.SE on the other hand is still in beta. We aren't even a full regular Stack Exchange site yet. If you look at the site stats, you will see that we have below average activity and member numbers. If you go to other writer communities, and ask about Writers.SE, most people there have never heard of it (and those that have often don't find it attractive, as the Q&A format does not fit the needs of writers very well – as I have often lamented here on meta). No one looking for a writer will come here to advertise. There are other venues that professional writers frequent, and there are other forums that are more alive than this site. That is the simple truth. What we need at this moment is more members. And for that, we might have to change. I once recommended this site for inclusion in a list of links to recommended ressources for writers. The reply was that Writers.SE is too technical writing oriented. Which is no surprise since most members here are people coming from Stack Overflow. I still suggest that we allow questions and answers of a different format. For example, many writing matters are a question of personal preferences, and there is no right and wrong about them, as it is about software. Programming code either runs or it doesn't. Writing on the other hand can appeal to different people, and therefore different answers are equally correct. So if we want this community to grow, we have to adapt it to the audience we want to attract, and not force writers to think like programmers. Until we do that, this community will remain small – and not need a job board.

Comment: Your comment about Writers being too oriented toward tech-writing made me laugh.  When I've promoted our site on tech-writing communities the main feedback I hear is that we're too fiction-oriented. :-)